# How to automatically name a file when saving in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to emulate in vim a behaviour similar to that of TextEdit.app.

As I work I often open a lot of files to take notes, and keep them there without saving them. When I restart the laptop, the TextEdit files will still be there and open thanks to [AutoSave](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4753).  If I do the same thing with vim (specifically MacVim) the files are (as expected) not saved and I lose their content.

My recipe for solving this problem has two bits. The first one is to automatically save the files when I'm not using them, so using a command like:

`autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost * silent! wall`

This works fine with files that have already been saved, but it ignores ones that have not yet been saved. This is where the second bit comes into play, I would like vim to automatically give these files a default name if it tries to save them and they don't already have a name. Possibly I would also like there to be a default save directory.

The ideal solution would be that when an unnamed file/buffer loses focus it gets saved as `~/Documents/notes/note_1.txt`, the second one `note_2.txt`, etc etc.

I did look around for any pointers that could help in either direction (default name and default directory - the latter is not fundamental though), but couldn't find anything.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5):

I don't like your idea, but it is doable.

You need a function:

```
function! SaveIt()
    if bufname("%")==''
        exec 'w /path/note_'.localtime()
    else
            w
    endif

endfunction
```

and in your autocommand, just call the function. Some points you need to note:

- the filename would be `/path/note_( ms since 1970)`. your `1,2,3..` index will make vim check filesystem to find out the index. It could be a better name, e.g `note_2013-09-11_11:11:11.233` You just change the `localtime()`
- this may throw exception when you try to save a readonly buffer. (help, qf ...) You could check for them though.
- Note that I didn't add the `!` in `w` cmd.
- it may not work for your autocmd `wall`. if you want to do it, you have to loop through all buffers, and for each buffer call the function.
- after all the function shows the direction how it could be done, it (the quality) is still very far away from "production" level.

Comment: +1 for "_I don't like your idea_" (and the quality info that follows).

Comment: Thanks Kent, that definitely puts me on the right track. 
I agree it's not clean - I will be renaming and properly saving all the files while I use them, but this is more of a safety net should something fail. Another option I thought of is autosaving every 30s or so, and I guess it would be done with a function similar to this one. If you have any other ideas they are more than welcome!

I'll give this a shot when I get to my desk before accepting - but great answer, thanks!